Properly setting BAD RAM in GRUB
lately I've started to experience instability with my system. At first, I suspected high temps, bad drivers, and so on... In the end I've decided to try Memtest86+, here is the result after 1 hour, with the BAD-RAM format selected.
First of all I want to specify that I can't change the RAM, it's soldered on the MOBO, I just want to have a normal experience with my device until I'm able to get a new one.

badram= 0x0000000232848000,0xfffffffffffff040,
        0x0000000232849040,0xfffffffffffff040,
        0x000000023284a000,0xfffffffffffff040,
        0x000000023284b060,0xfffffffffffff060,
        0x000000023284c040,0xffffffffffffd440,
        0x000000023284c420,0xffffffffffffe520,
        0x000000023284d110,0xfffffffffffff550,
        0x000000023284e020,0xffffffffffffe528,
        0x000000023284e020,0xffffffffffffe020,
        0x000000023284f000,0xfffffffffffff040

My problem:
I want to set somehow the GRUB_BADRAM variable in the etc/default/grub file.
What I've tried:

GRUB_BADRAM="0x0000000232848000,0xfffffffffffff040,0x0000000232849040,0xfffffffffffff040,0x000000023284a000,0xfffffffffffff040,0x000000023284b060,0xfffffffffffff060,0x000000023284c040,0xffffffffffffd440,0x000000023284c420,0xffffffffffffe520,0x000000023284d110,0xfffffffffffff550,0x000000023284e020,0xffffffffffffe528,0x000000023284e020,0xffffffffffffe020,0x000000023284f000,0xfffffffffffff040"
for short, the result of memtest, just in a one-liner. Result? Not being able to boot at all, needed to use a live USB to comment out the line and do a update-grub command.

Being that the detected bad RAM ranges seem rather small I wanted to cover the whole range with just one address-mask pair: 0x0000000232848000 and the mask ... ? I don't really understand how it works TBH.


Thanks!

shouldn't these address be page-aligned? Meaning that all their last three hex digits need to be null. It would seem to me you would one entry, badram=0x232848000,0xffffffffffff8000. Note that this is all impossible if you have secureboot active.
